# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\views\posts\index.ctp on line 43

Tags: cakephp

When I am trying to run my program i found this error and my code in CakePHP is

`Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\cakephp\app\views\posts\index.ctp on line 43`

and my CODE IS

```
'/posts/edit/'.$post['Post]['id']);?>
```

Comment: please paste the entire line and the line before

Comment: <?php echo $html->link(
   'Edit',
   '/posts/edit/'.$post['Post]['id']);?>
   </td>

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    echo $html->link('Edit', '/posts/edit/' . $post['Post']['id']);
?> </td>
```

There was a missing '

Comment: @UserCakePHP see ['Post]